# Black Screen while installing Kali Linux on Mac M1 through UTM

Tags: kali-linux, system-installation, virtual-machine, ios

Whenever I try to install Linux through [UTM](https://getutm.app/), I get a black screen after the installation.

Does anyone know what we need to do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem is the following:

1.- You will have to choose: The display option | Emulated Display Card - virtio-ramfb

2.- Add a Serial under Devices from the settings options of the VM

3.- You will get a screen asking you what type of software you want to install. Then, you will have to install Kali Linux without any software, you will have to uncheck all of the software that has been checked by default.

4.- After you get a prompt window with "The installation is ready" You have to eject the ISO image

5.- Restart the machine, and login with your credentials

6.- Run the following commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install -y kali-desktop-kde
sudo update-alternatives --config x-session-manager
```

[image: Settings]

[image: UTM screen]
[image: Kali Linux Desktop Image]

This will solve the black screen. I just downloaded the latest version of Kali and UTM, please ping me if you have any questions.

Comment: The important part of this answer is adding a Serial device to see the output. Nothing else here matters.